# How To Iterate Through Numbered Properties in Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a large Object with over 700 properties all numbered.  How can I iterate through every numbered property?

```
{ '0': 
   { emails: 
      { categorized: [Object],
        all: [Object],
        primary: 'support@wish.com' },
     id: '290cb70ea0f',
     updated: '2011-09-16T05:55:12.136Z' },
  '1': 
   { emails: 
      { categorized: [Object],
        all: [Object],
        primary: 'VJONO@csnfo.com' },
     id: '753ac508e1a00e',
     updated: '2012-07-12T22:23:11.196Z' },
  '2': 
   { title: 'Bryan Weston',
     phone_numbers: { categorized: [Object], all: [Object], primary: '' },
     id: 'b4c0268d92825e',
     updated: '2010-10-13T08:00:32.834Z' },
    // It goes on....
```

Comment: How about using an array of objects, with indices?

Comment: Only the numbered properties? or is there other properties on the object

Comment: ONly the numbered properties.  Should I put these into an array then iterate through them?  This was received via an AJAX POST request so instead of submitting an array it submitted an object...

Comment: Yes, you should send a collection. Object properties are not guaranteed to appear in specific order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure javascript it would go something like this

```
var data = { /*stuff*/ };
var item;
for (var prop in data) {
   //hasOwn is probably not needed
   if( /*data.hasOwnProperty(prop) &&*/ !isNaN(prop) ) {  //only do stuff if the property is a number
       item = data[prop];
       //work
   }
}
```

With Underscore you would write it as in Mark's answer but with a similar `if(!isNaN(prop))` or `_.isNaN` check

Answer (score 2):

use underscore.

```
_.each(yourObject, function (item, index) {
   console.log(item.emails);
   console.log(item.title);
   // etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var objectKeys = Object.keys(yourObject).map(Number);
objectKeys.sort();
for(var i=0;i < objectKeys.length; i++) {
    key = objectKeys[i];
    element = yourObject[key];
    //do magic here
}
```

If you don't care about order of processing, you can just use `for(key in youObject)`